# Proof Check on Change of Variables Result

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $g: I \to \mathbb{R}$ be strictly increasing with continuous derivative on an open interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$.  Let $\mu$ be the measure on $(I, \mathcal{B}(I))$ with density $g^\prime$ w.r.t. Lebesgue measure $\lambda$.

**Claim**: $\mu$ is the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure for $g$.  That is, $\mu((a,b]) = g(b) - g(a)$.

**Proof**
\begin{align*}
\mu((a,b]) & = \int_{(a,b]} g^\prime\, \mathrm{d}\lambda &\qquad& \text{def'n density} \\
& = \int_a^b g^\prime(x) \, \mathrm{d} x &\qquad& g^\prime \text{ continuous on } (a,b] \\
& = g(b) - g(a) &\qquad& \text{FTC}.
\end{align*}

Does this seem correct?  I know this is related to the change of variables theorem, so I assume this is just a very specific case.

Comment: Right.${}{}{}{}$